# Solve an equation with real parameters

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, trigonometry

I am trying to solve
$$
\left(\eta ^2-1\right) \cosh ^2(\beta  \eta )+2 J^2=2 \eta  (J \sinh (\beta  \eta ) \sinh (\beta  J)+\eta  \cosh (\beta  \eta ) \cosh (\beta  J)) 
$$
for $\eta$. Where, $\beta, J$ are positive and reals, and $B$ is real. I used

```
Reduce[2 J^2 + (η^2 - 1) Cosh[ β η]^2 == 
   2 η (η Cosh[J β] Cosh[β η] + 
      J Sinh[J β] Sinh[β η]) && η > 0 && 
  J > 0 && β > 0, η, Reals]
```

with no answers.

Comment: I suspect that this might be a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) with no analytic solution.

Answer (score 2):

`ContourPlot3D` shows the solution in parameterspace:

```
ContourPlot3D[2 J^2 + (\[Eta]^2 - 1) Cosh[\[Beta] \[Eta]]^2 ==2 \[Eta] (\[Eta] Cosh[J \[Beta]] Cosh[\[Beta] \[Eta]] +J Sinh[J \[Beta]] Sinh[\[Beta] \[Eta]]), {J, 0, 3}, {\[Beta], 0, 5}, {\[Eta], 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic ]
```

There are two solutions for `J>1/Sqrt[2]` and one for `0<J<1/Sqrt[2]`
[image]

Comment: @yarchik The parameterspace `{J, \[Beta], \[Eta]}` is threedimansional, that's why I prefer `ContourPlot3D` .

Comment: You are right. However, I was wondering  how many solution branches are there. `ContourPlot[(2 J^2 + (η^2 - 1) Cosh[ β η]^2 == 
   2 η (η Cosh[J β] Cosh[β η] + 
      J Sinh[J β] Sinh[β η]))/.{J->1/Sqrt[2]}, {η,-100,100},{β,-100,100}]` does not give me any.

Comment: It's necessary to evaluate the argument of `ContourPlot`. Try `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[2 J^2 + (\[Eta]^2 - 1) Cosh[\[Beta] \[Eta]]^2 == 
    2 \[Eta] (\[Eta] Cosh[J \[Beta]] Cosh[\[Beta] \[Eta]] + 
       J Sinh[J \[Beta]] Sinh[\[Beta] \[Eta]]) /. J -> 1/Sqrt[2]]
 , {\[Eta], 0, 10}, {\[Beta], 0, 5}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]` ,  this gives one branch.